# Приподнять блок слова на 10px

Tags: html, css, позиционирование

Необходимо приподнять слово на 10px как на фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам блок `out-6`

```html
<p class="out-6">
Граф Дра́кула (англ. Count Dracula) — вампир, заглавный персонаж и главный
<span class="s-6">антагонист</span>
романа Брэма Стокера «Дракула» (1897). В качестве архетипического вампира 
Дракула появлялся во множестве произведений массовой культуры, даже не имеющих 
непосредственного отношения к роману Брэма Стокера.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Элементы с `position: relative` остаются там где были, но теперь к ним можно применять абсолютное позиционирование, в нашем случае `top`.

```css
span {
  top: -10px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<p>Граф Дра́кула (англ. Count Dracula) — вампир, заглавный персонаж и главный <span>антагонист</span> романа Брэма Стокера «Дракула» (1897). В качестве архетипического вампира Дракула появлялся во множестве произведений массовой культуры, даже не имеющих непосредственного отношения к роману Брэма Стокера.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `transform: translateY(-10px)`, но перед этим нужно, чтобы к блоку можно было применять блочные свойства. Для этого можно ему задать `display: inline-block`

```css
.sup {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<p>Граф Дра́кула (англ. Count Dracula) — вампир, заглавный персонаж и главный <span class="sup">антагонист</span> романа Брэма Стокера «Дракула» (1897). В качестве архетипического вампира Дракула появлялся во множестве произведений массовой культуры, даже не имеющих непосредственного отношения к роману Брэма Стокера.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы вам не использовать для этого `vertical-align`?

```css
.s-6 {
  vertical-align: super;
}
```

```html
<p class="out-6">
Граф Дра́кула (англ. Count Dracula) — вампир, заглавный персонаж и главный
<span class="s-6">антагонист</span>
романа Брэма Стокера «Дракула» (1897). В качестве архетипического вампира 
Дракула появлялся во множестве произведений массовой культуры, даже не имеющих 
непосредственного отношения к роману Брэма Стокера.
</p>
```